# Static site, server side computation, Nextjs, WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, next.js, server-side-rendering, static-site

I want to create a mostly static site (and have been thinking about using *Next.js*), however it should include the possibility to get a price estimate based on customer specifications. This **computation should be private** and shouldn't be revealed to anyone (otherwise I would have inserted plain js). I'm guessing I need to have something listening for requests on the server and give back some simple response (the price).

I am using Host-Europe's Webbuilder pack and have ssh access. To set up WordPress (and be able to reach the setup main page), all I had to do, was copy over the files and assign the domain to the WordPress folder in Host-Europe's admin panel.

So, my questions are:

- Is adding this functionality easily achievable with a static website framework or is it advisable to just completely switch to some server-side rendering framework (such as *WordPress, React, Django*)
- Do I need some process running in the background listening for requests? How would I call such a process to trigger some server-side function via JavaScript for example and obtain the result?
- Why was it not required to start some demon process for WordPress to work? (I'm guessing Host-Europe might be involved in the background here?)

I would prefer to stick to either *Node/JavaScript* or *Python* if it comes down to using some framework, but anything that gets the job done quick for now would be great.

I have built my own static blog before and hosted it on github-pages, but I am a bit clueless when it comes to anything beyond that.

Comment: Can you just use Google Cloud or AWS to create a cloud function that does your calculation and then use node or react with axious to send an http request to the cloud resource where your function lives and have it return the price to display?

Comment: Since the page is already hosted with the current provider I would like to find a solution that doesn't require cloud services. Although, I might look into that if there is no other possibility.

Comment: You can always build an API with node or Python if you want on your server but AWS lambda is free for 1 million requests. You can set up a really quick endpoint and a node function to do your calculation and start making requests. Otherwise, you may want to create node js/express js REST API and host it with your current provider.

Comment: Another practical solution is having the calculation in javascript but loaded from an external source. You can minify the javascript to obfuscate the calculation code.

Comment: Oh, if its free that's great. I'll look into it. However, if I wanted to create a simple API myself, what would you recommend? And how would I be able to send the information with the request and receive the output data?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do calculations in JavaScript, load from an external source on your server and minify the js code to obfuscate it. Probably the easiest solution in my opinion.
2. You can utilize AWS Lambda functions and get your first 1 million requests free.
3. Create a simple REST API with Node.JS and Express JS.

Node.js Express.js API example

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/calculate-price', (req, res) => {
  response_price = req.query.parameter1 + req.query.parameter2
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ price: response_price }));
})
```

The Next JS fetch function

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
   const res = await fetch(`https:[your API or cloud function resource]?parameter1=abc&parameter2=1245`)
   const data = await res.json()

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
     props: { data }, // the price will be passed to the page component as props
   }
}
```